# Doing development while awaiting A2P 10DLC?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is there a development mode while waiting on A2P?
Brand is registered and approved, but now awaiting on campaign

Just want to get dev moving forward

Was hoping for something where we could have a pool of 3 or so numbers that we can send and receive replies to / from. Do dev, demos, testing, get sign off etc..

Is there something I'm missing?

Google karma isn't working for me on this one

Comment: You can start development without waiting for the A2P registration approval. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: Yeah - can't receive replies via webhooks; I can send which makes zero sense.

Comment: Not receiving the webhook calls is very likely issue with the webhook setup or the API implementation. I don't think Twilio is blocking webhooks because of the A2P 10DLC status.

Comment: Error: 30034 message from an unregistered a2p 10dlc number;  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30034 suspect it's copy pasta error message